# I want to uninstall Ubuntu social kit completely

Tags: uninstall, software-uninstall

I want to uninstall Ubuntu social kit but when I click on remove (in Ubuntu software) it disappears from Ubuntu software but still remains in my laptop then on reboot again comes in Ubuntu software I want to delete it completely how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

anything in Ubuntu Software UI can also be done from the terminal ... open up a terminal  (  ctrl-alt-t )

lets see the installed package

```
dpkg -l | grep  ubuntu-social-kit
```

if you see a match here then we have the correct package name so just remove it

```
sudo apt remove --purge   ubuntu-social-kit
```

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu-Social-Kit is a so called "snap" package, with this command I succeeded to uninstall Ubuntu-Social-Kit

```
sudo snap remove package-name
```

Answer (score 0):

Snaps are fundamentally different from regular distro packages. They are completely separate from the stock package management system. They cannot be managed by apt.

A snap package's bits are installed to and managed in either `/snap` or `~/snap` by the snap daemon. The only way to uninstall them is with a snap command. A similar next-gen package system found on the latest releases of Fedora (but that also works on Ubuntu, just as rpm can) is called flatpak.

There's also a third alternative called AppImage. As a result, the threshold question whenever dealing with package install/uninstall issues have become, "Which (of potentially 4) package system is in play?".